# Describe command in DB2 data studio

Tags: db2

My new Project is using DB2 9.7 version, and the GUI used is Data Studio. But the basic `Describe` command is not recognized. The query I am using is:

```
 DESCRIBE table Select * from  risk.risk_basic
```

and the error am getting is :

> unexpected token "DESCRIBE Select *" was found following
>   "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT"

Comment: DESCRIBE is a command and not a SQL statement, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

As @data_henrik wrote it is a command and cannot be executed through a JDBC connection. YOu could switch the editor connection to a DB2 Server Command Line Processor though ...
This is described in the following answer of mine

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161117/reorg-command-does-not-work-in-ibm-data-studio-but-same-works-in-command-line-pr

Comment: @diva rajamohan  if it works for you please flag it as answered. This is how stackoverflow works - thanks